# List databases and tables of a server in VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to list the databases and the tables of a server.

I have tried using [`OpenSchema`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/openschema-method) like in [this example](https://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_listdb/) but it returns null when doing:

```
Set Recordset1 = Connection.OpenSchema(Schema:=ADODB.SchemaEnum.adSchemaSchemata)
MsgBox Prompt:=VBA.IsNull(Expression:=Recordset1.Fields.Item(Index:=0))
```

I have some code below that works for a MySQL server but I'm interested in knowing one way that is more standard and not specific to one DBMS.

```
' Reference:
' Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library

Private Sub Macro()

  Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
  Dim Recordset1 As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim Recordset2 As ADODB.Recordset

  Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
  Connection.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306"
  Connection.ConnectionTimeout = 0
  Connection.Open UserId:="root", Password:=""
  Set Recordset1 = New ADODB.Recordset
  Recordset1.ActiveConnection = Connection
  Recordset1.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
  Recordset1.Source = "SHOW DATABASES"
  Recordset1.Open
  Set Recordset2 = New ADODB.Recordset
  Recordset2.ActiveConnection = Connection
  Recordset2.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
  Do While Not Recordset1.EOF
    Connection.Execute "USE " & Recordset1.Fields.Item(Index:="Database").Value
    Recordset2.Source = "SHOW TABLES"
    Recordset2.Open
    Do While Not Recordset2.EOF
      Debug.Print Recordset1.Fields.Item(Index:=0).Value & " - " & Recordset2.Fields.Item(Index:=0).Value
      Recordset2.MoveNext
    Loop
    Recordset2.Close
    Recordset1.MoveNext
  Loop
  Set Recordset2 = Nothing
  Recordset1.Close
  Set Recordset1 = Nothing
  Connection.Close
  Set Connection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Write it as a stored procedure in sql then exec that from excel. I assume that is possible as with sql server. You can then write some nice dynamic sql backend to handle the loops over dbs for example. Again, I am extrapolating from what I do with SQL Server.

Comment: @QHarr I'm looking more for a solution on the VBA side that would work for example with a connection with read-only permission to an external server.

Comment: `Recordset.OpenSchema` gives you *metadata* about the query results, e.g. column names, data types, field lengths, etc. Assuming `SHOW TABLES` does what SQL Server does with `select * from sys.tables`, then you want a normal recordset, not its metadata.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon So if I wanted to list the databases and tables from a connection provided by the user I would have to hardcode the list of ways to get them for each different DBMS? For example `SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM all_tables` for Oracle.

Comment: If you need to support multiple RDBMS, consider abstracting the data access code behind some `ISomethingRepository` interface (say, exposing some `GetAllTablesInfo` method), and implementing that interface with `SqlSomethingRepository`, `OracleSomethingRepository`, and/or `MySqlSomethingRepository` classes, then code against `ISomethingRepository` and leverage *polymorphism* to make the code work with any RDBMS, without needing to rewrite all the data access code; to support a new RDBMS, simply implement the interface and use the new class. c.f. "dependency injection" and OOP.

Comment: Note that Oracle's `all_table`, SQL Server's `sys.tables`, and MySQL's `SHOW TABLES` are not really the same thing as extracting information from ADO's `OpenSchema`. The latter provides you a view of how ADO sees their schema with the current capabilities. Since you are doing this from VBA, you should be using ADO's POV, not the former's POV which is arguably more complete and conforms closely to the actual capabilities but that's not what you're interested in. You're interested in metadata as ADO understand it in order to work efficiently from VBA side.

Comment: ^ i.e. `OpenSchema` gives you a recordset that contains *metadata* about the query results: field names, data types, field lengths, nullability, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every RDBMS has its own flavor of SQL. SQL Server supports *table-valued functions* and *common table expressions* (CTE), MySQL doesn't but has a neat `group_concat` function; Oracle has a different syntax, Access has its own limitations and particularities, DB2 as well - you're extremely lucky if you can write a SQL query that works on every RDBMS out there.

With a *procedural* approach, you need a way for your code to know what flavor of SQL to use. You could use an `Enum`:

```vb
Public Enum RDBMS
    NotSupported
    SqlServer
    MySql
    Oracle
End Enum
```

And then you would have switching logic to get the correct SQL syntax for what you need to do:

```vb
Private Function GetTableInfoQuery(ByVal db As RDBMS) As String
    Select Case db
        Case SqlServer
            GetTableInfoQuery = "SELECT * FROM sys.Tables;"
        Case MySql
            GetTableInfoQuery = "MySQL-specific query;"
        Case Oracle
            GetTableInfoQuery = "Oracle-specific query;"
        Case Else
            Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "Specified RDBMS is not supported"
     End Select
End Function
```

This will work, but quickly gets annoyingly verbose, and you now have multiple functions containing different flavors of SQL syntax (and more for the different connection strings), and maintaining that eventually becomes a nightmare - let alone debugging it.

The problem isn't with supporting multiple RDBMS, the problem is the procedural approach. Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) brings cleaner ones. In any typical C# or Java data-access code, the RDBMS is abstracted away from the consuming code using an *interface* - the "pattern" is dubbed *Repository*, and the main advantage of it is that the consuming code simply couldn't care less what RDBMS it's working with.

Define an interface exposing the functionality you need:

```vb
'@Interface "ITableInfoRepository"
Option Explicit

Public Function GetTableInfo() As Object
End Function
```

Typically a more general-purpose repository interface might look like this:

```vb
Public Function GetAll() As Object
End Function

Public Function GetById(ByVal id As Long) As Object
End Function

Public Sub Delete(ByVal id As Long)
End Sub

Public Sub Save(ByVal entity As Object)
End Sub
```

In languages that support *generics*, you wouldn't need `As Object` and you could preserve type-safety - but since VBA doesn't support generics (e.g. `List(Of Something)` in VB.NET), `Object` is good enough.

So the idea is to code against that `IRepository` interface:

```vb
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal repository As ITableInfoRepository)
    Dim infos As Object
    Set infos = repository.GetTableInfo
    '...do stuff...
End Sub
```

Note how `DoSomething` only knows about the `ITableInfoRepository` abstract interface, and doesn't care if that's actually hitting SQL Server, MySQL, or Oracle. Near (or *at*) the entry point of your code/macro, you'll be creating the instances of the actual concrete types:

```vb
Public Sub Macro1()
    Dim repository As ITableInfoRepository
    Set repository = New SqlTableInfoRepository
    DoSomething repository
    '...
End Sub
```

If `Macro1` suddenly needs to work off a `MySqlTableInfoRepository`, then implement the `ITableInfoRepository` interface on a new `MySqlTableInfoRepository` class module, and instantiate that class instead: `DoSomething` won't bat an eye.

You *implement* an interface using the `Implements` keyword. For example the `SqlTableInfoRepository` implementation might look like this:

```vb
Option Explicit
Implements ITableInfoRepository

Private Function ITableInfoRepository_GetTableInfo() As Object
    Const sql = "SELECT * FROM sys.Tables"
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    '...
End Function
```

You could make `GetTableInfo` return the `ADODB.Recordset`, but then the column names might be different between different implementations, and you don't want that. So either you make sure all implementations `SELECT` the same columns, or you abstract the query results behind an *entity* object that formalizes what a "table info" record looks like, and return a collection of these *entities*:

```vb
'TableInfoEntity (class)
Option Explicit
Public DatabaseName As String
Public TableName As String 'SQL Server: includes 'dbo' schema
Public ColumnName As String
Public DataType As String
'...
```

Similarly, if you have a `SqlOrderHeaderRepository`, you might have a `OrderHeaderEntity` class module, so that all `IRepository` implementations that deal with *order headers* have the same concept of what an *order header* looks like:

```vb
Option Explicit
Public OrderDate As Date
Public CustomerID As Long
Public SalesRepID As Long
Public Description As String
'...
```

That way `DoSomething` (or whatever code is consuming the `IRepository` interface) doesn't even need to know about ADODB, and can work with `OrderHeaderEntity`, `OrderDetailEntity`, `CustomerEntity`, `SalesRepEntity`, and whatever other classes make up your *domain*.

Yes, OOP is more work, and more modules. But the result is that you're now looking at modules with clearly-defined responsibilities, with SQL Server syntax in one place, MySQL syntax in another, and Oracle syntax in another module - without any switching logic anywhere. To extend it and support a new RDBMS, you don't even need to touch the existing code - you simply implement the classes you need so that the code can work with the new RDBMS, and you wire it all up at the entry point: once done, all you need to do to swap the RDBMS is to change the concrete classes you're instantiating and parameter-injecting into the consuming code at the entry point.